# A little help needed catching events being raised inside a seperate thread

Tags: c#, events, delegates

To begin, I'm working on a pretty high level file system where I need to be able to (with very pin point accuracy) identify and process files in a timely manner.  With that said, I am working on a system that will be using the FileSystemWatcher.  The whole problem with the watcher though is the fact that it tends to have issues when throwing events when there are large files involved.

To remedy this I'm working on an abstract class that can handle the files individualy once they are created by the file system watcher.

The current road block that I am running into is that my out of process validation on the file is throwing an event, I'm just having problems catching it.

```
public abstract class absFile
    {
        public delegate void FileAvailable(object sender, FileEventArgs e);
        public event FileAvailable OnFileAvailable;

        public void isAvailable()
        {
            // Create a new threaded instance of the AvailableCheck private void
            // This method will be run out of process to allow other operations to continue.
            Thread toAvailableCheck = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AvailableCheck));

            // Once the threaded object is created, start it.
            toAvailableCheck.Start();
        }

 private void AvailableCheck()
        {
            // Declaring the file stream toThisFile to be used later with the File.Open
            FileStream toThisFile;

            // Declaring and instantiating the attempt counter for the loop
            int tiAttemptNumber = 0;

            // Declaring the event args for returning the events that are
            // used by this object.

            FileEventArgs toFileEventArgs = new FileEventArgs();

            do {
                try
                {
                    // Attempt to open the file.  If this fails the try
                    // will interrupt the processing and it will be caught.
                    toThisFile = File.Open(this.FilePath, FileMode.Open);

                    // If the file.open method does not fail, the isFileAvailable
                    // property will be set to true by updating the mbIsAvailable
                    // private boolean.
                    mbIsAvailable = true;

                    // populate the file event args to send back 
                    // the number of attempts made at the file and the pause lenght
                    toFileEventArgs.Attempts = tiAttemptNumber;
                    toFileEventArgs.Pause = this.AttemptPause / 1000;

                    // This event is called when the file is complete.
                    // The client application will be able to handle this event.
                    OnFileAvailable(this, toFileEventArgs);


                    // close and dispose of the filestream.
                    toThisFile.Close();
                    toThisFile.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception toException)
                {
                    // Since the open failed, add 1 to the counter so that
                    // it will eventually time out.
                    tiAttemptNumber++;

                    // Set the isFileAvailable property to false.  This property
                    // will default as false, but as a part of standard, make sure that
                    // if the open fails that the flag IS set to false by updating the 
                    // mbIsAvailable private boolean.
                    mbIsAvailable = false;

                    // Put the thread to sleep for the ammount of time specified
                    // by the AttemptPause.  This will give the file time to finish
                    // whatever process it is involved in.
                    Thread.Sleep(this.AttemptPause);
                }

              // Continue to make attempts until either the file is marked as available
              // or the number of current attempts is the same as or greater than the
              // AccessAttempts property.
            } while (!this.isFileAvailable && this.AccessAttempts > tiAttemptNumber);
        }
```

this is the code that I am running as you can see in the private void AvailableCheck, OnfileAvailable is the delegate called passing back this and the file event args.

now i have inherited this abstract class, and i need to be able to catch that event.

```
        toWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
```

is called in the main and farther down the code is the following method

```
private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lstStatus.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
        lstStatus.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + " - " + e.Name + " - File Created Event Detected for: " + e.FullPath);
        lstStatus.TopIndex = lstStatus.Items.Count - 1;
        tgtFile ThisFile = new tgtFile(e.FullPath);
        lstStatus.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + " - " + e.Name + " - Creating tgtFile Object");
    }));
}
```

The instatiation of the tgtFile object is passed the path which makes its way down the pike to the is available method.

as you can see the chance exists for the OnFileAvailable event to be fired from the tgtFile object.

Also as you can see, the the possibility for multiple tgtFile objects to exist in memory at the same time is there as well based on the threading design of the filesystemwatcher.

in my main application then i want to be able to do something like:

```
public tgtFile ThisFile;
ThisFile.OnFileAvailable += new EventHandler(OnFileAvailable);
```

but the EventHandler errors out, and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Is it Raising an event or Throwing an exception?

Comment: raising events. there are no exceptions being thrown

Comment: And what exactly is an "out-of-process" thread?

Comment: its not in the same process as the application.

Comment: Then how do you subscribe to it without any plumbing? (such as old-school remoting?)

Comment: they are on the same server. i would assume that main application would still be able to handle events from a thread that it created.

Comment: I changed the title. I think your getting hung up on the out-of-process... this is not a true out of process system (COM, processing being done on other servers and such...) it is multi-threaded.

Comment: "but the EventHandler errors out, and that is where I am stuck."  What do you mean by "errors out"-  compiler error, exception, hang?  What is the error?  what is the code that is causing the error?   You've given us tons of convoluted and questionable detail setting up the background to your issue, but then no details at all on your actual problem.

Comment: @Philip - For that particular piece of code, it gives me an "invalid type" compile error on the EventHandler. I'll be sure to leave out all of my convoluted and questionable detail next time because I bet you just LOVE those types of questions where there is nothing to go on when trying to figgure out what they are talking about. My mistake on leaving out the error message, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is giving you a compiler error, it's probably because your "OnFileAvailable" method referenced in this line (from the bottom of your post):

```
ThisFile.OnFileAvailable += new EventHandler(OnFileAvailable);
```

is not expecting an `EventHandler` - it's expecting a `FileAvailable` delegate.  Change it to:

```
ThisFile.OnFileAvailable += new absFile.FileAvailable(OnFileAvailable);
//note that this can also just be ThisFile.OnFileAvailable += OnFileAvailable;
```

and make sure OnFileAvailable looks like this:

```
public void OnFileAvailable(object sender, FileEventArgs e)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first...  Ensure the event is subscribed, before calling it.  Wrap the event call in an IF statement:

```
if (OnFileAvailable != null)
    OnFileAvailable(this, toFileEventArgs);
```

Comment: Actually, you'd want to assign the OnFileAvailable to a local variable to avoid a race condition. e.g. var handler = OnFileAvailable; if (handler != null) handler(this, toFileEventArgs);

Comment: I'm honestly not concerned at the moment about that particular detail because I am able to get to that line of code and it is being run properly every time i debug, plus it is in a try catch, so if i start having issues where that particular part of the code is failing i'll handle it in the catch itself.